# Vector length comparison whose names are stored in a cell

Tags: matlab

There are vectors in workspace with different vector lengths.  I have a string cell that contains vector names.  I want to use cellfun to spit out the length of these vectors.

for example,

```
t1 = 1x10 double
t2 = 1x100 double
t3 = 1x20 double
cel = {'t1','t2','t3'};

cellfun(@(c) eval(['length(',c{:},')']),cel)
```

I thought doing the following will do the job, but it doesn't.  I have reasons why I need to use cellfun and eval for this problem.

Can somebody point out what's wrong?  The error messages I get are:

```
cellfun(@(c) eval(['length(',c{:},')']),cel)
Cell contents reference from a non-cell array object.

cellfun(@(c) eval(['length(',c(:),')']),cel)
Error using horzcat
Dimensions of matrices being concatenated are not consistent.

cellfun(@(c) eval(['length(',[c{:}],')']),yvar)
Cell contents reference from a non-cell array object.
```

depending on the variation I tried.

or better yet.  The end goal is to check if the length for all the vectors is the same.  If there is a way to do so without looping, that'd be great.

Comment: This seems like a great reason to change your code so you don't need `eval`. Also, `cellfun` is a loop, and almost always slower than the explicit loop so you're not really saving anything there either.

Comment: Thank you for the great information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [whos](https://nl.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/whos.html)

```
L={}
for ct = 1:length(cell)
    w=whos(cel{ct});
    L{ct} = w.size;
end
```

And I agree with the comment. Rewrite the code so you don't need weird workarounds.

Answer (score 2):

> I have reasons why I need to use `cellfun` and `eval` for this problem.

This question, and the questions that are sure to follow, are fantastic reasons *not* to use `eval`. Ever. Ever ever ever. It's hard to debug, it's slow (`eval` statements are ignored by MATLAB's JIT compiler), and it makes pretty much everything more complicated than it needs to be.

If you absolutely, totally, seriously cannot avoid using `eval` (a situation that very rarely exists), you can cobble something together using the optional output of [`whos`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/whos.html):

For example:

```
t1 = rand(1, 10);
t2 = rand(1, 100);
t3 = rand(1, 20);
t4 = rand(1, 1, 20);
cel = {'t1', 't2', 't3', 't4'};

ws = whos();
tmp = {ws.name};
sizes = {ws(ismember(tmp, cel)).size}
```

Returns a cell array of the sizes of the matching variables, which you can use to make whatever further analysis you need.

If you know that your data is only going to be two dimensional, you can drop the size information into an array and [`reshape`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/reshape.html) it to something easily parsable visually:

```
t1 = rand(1, 10);
t2 = rand(1, 100);
t3 = rand(1, 20);
cel = {'t1', 't2', 't3'};

ws = whos();
tmp = {ws.name};
sizes = reshape([ws(ismember(tmp, cel)).size], 2, []).';
```

---

`whos` also supports [regular expressions](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/regular-expressions.html), which allow you to match variables based on a pattern rather than having to populate a cell array:

```
t1 = rand(1, 10);
t2 = rand(1, 100);
t3 = rand(1, 20);
v1 = rand(1, 30);
time = rand(1, 5);

ws = whos('-regexp', 't\d+');
tmp = {ws.name};
sizes = reshape([ws.size], 2, []).';
```

Comment: I strive not to use eval.  It is indeed a rare case in my gigantic code.  Thank you.